# GLEW Vertex Shader compile error

Tags: c++, glsl, glew

I recently started working on Vertex and Fragment shaders in GLEW. For some reason I am getting a failed to compile shader error.

The error I am getting is as follow:

```
Failed to compile vertex shader: Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:3 error (#12) Unexpected qualifier.
ERROR: 0:3 error(#132) Syntax error: "position" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors. No code generated.
```

The text document that contain the code for the shader is:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in Vector4 position;

uniform Matrix pr_matrix;
uniform Matrix vw_matrix = Matrix(1, 0);
uniform Matrix ml_matrix = Matrix(1, 0);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = /*pr_matrix **/ position;
}
```

And the code that compile the shader is:

```
GLuint Shader::load() {
        GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
        GLuint vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLuint fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        std::string vertexSourceString = File::read_file(mVertex);
        std::string fragmentSourceString = File::read_file(mFragment);

        const char* vertexSource = vertexSourceString.c_str();
        const char* fragmentSource = fragmentSourceString.c_str();

        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);

        GLint result;
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

        if (result == GL_FALSE) {
            GLint length;
            glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            std::vector<char> error(length);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, length, &length, &error[0]);
            std::cout << "Failed to compile vertex shader: " << &error[0] << std::endl;
            glDeleteShader(vertex);

            return 0;
        }

        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

        if (result == GL_FALSE) {
            GLint length;
            glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            std::vector<char> error(length);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, length, &length, &error[0]);
            std::cout << "Failed to compile fragment shader: " << &error[0] << std::endl;
            glDeleteShader(fragment);

            return 0;
        }

        glAttachShader(program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glValidateProgram(program);
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);

        return program;
```

}

I think something is wrong with the vertex, if anyone can help I will appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings `Vertex4` and `Matrix` have no meaning for GLSL.  Types in GLSL are things like `vec4` and `mat4`

Comment: Oh. I thought Vec4, and Mat4 were suppose to be classes I created. Not GLEW built in. Thanks.

Comment: They have nothing to do with GLEW -- the shader is written in GLSL, a completely self-contained language independent of C or C++.